# Как вывести на экран первое слово в строке?

Tags: java

Нужно вывести первое слово в строке. Пробовал присваивать переменной char символы строки и выводить их до пробела. Ничего не вышло.

```
int c = 0;
while (char b = fam.get(i).charAt(c); b != " "; c++)
   {
      System.out.println(b);
   }
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как будет правильно?

Comment: 1.

String input = "Первое второе третье";

String[] array = input.split(" ");

System.out.println(array[0]);



2.
String data = "Первое второе третье";  

StringTokenizer tokens = new StringTokenizer(data, " "); 
 
System.out.println(tokens.nextElement());

Answer (score 1):

отформатировал ваш код:

```
int c = 0; 
while (
    char b = fam.get(i).charAt(c); 
    b != " "; 
    c++) 
{ 
    System.out.println(b); 
}
```

**О боже, вот это каша у вас в голове!**

Даже не знаю что посоветовать и куда послать почитать.

1. для начала я думаю стоит
       разобраться, чем отличаются циклы
       for(){}, while(){} и do{}while()
2. затем я думаю стоит разобраться с
       выводом

   ```
   System.out.print()
   System.out.printf()
   System.out.println()
   ```

Comment: Строка b != " "; не проходит. А код предложенный выше прошел. String input = "Первое второе третье";
String[] array = input.split(" ");
System.out.println(array[0]);  

Спасибо большое!

Comment: разумеется он не работает!

@gloryz вы издеваетесь? я скопировал и отформатировал ваш же код из вашего вопроса, разве что правильно отформатировал дабы показать ту ересь что вы написали!

срочно прекращайте копипастить  и беритесь за учёбу иначе никогда не станете программистом (и даже кодером)